# Add image file upload field to WooCommerce single products

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, woocommerce, product

i have created a custom plugin which dynamically displays custom fields in woocommerce single product page.
Fields are displayed, added to cart and added to order data and emails.
However i'm trying for days to add a file upload field with no luck.
The field is displayed in the frontend like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'display_custom_fields' );
function display_custom_fields() {
?>
    <p class="form-row validate-required" id="image" >
        <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
        <label for="image" class=""><?php echo $stamp_welcome_text; ?> </label> 
        
        <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" >
        </span>
    </p>
<?php
}
```

and then added to cart like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_cart_item_data', 10,3 );
function add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
    if ($_FILES['image'] ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
        $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'image', 0 );
        if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) AND $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) {
            die($attachment_id->get_error_message().'. Παρακαλώ επικοινωνήστε μαζί μας.');
        } else $cart_item_data['image'] = $attachment_id;
    }
    return $item_cart_data;
}
```

Of course this is only part of the code.The rest of the fields are working perfect. Yes, i have tried the code only by itself if anyone wonders.

I have been "playing" around with it for days and i can't figure out what's wrong.
Any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the `<form>` tag? Also, is there potentially a firewall in the middle that is blocking things?

Comment: @Chris Haas i have just verified that the tag is present. I had also wordfence installed, which i just disabled to see if something changes but i got the same results.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try the following, that will store uploaded image data as custom cart item data and save it as custom order item meta data:

```
// Display additional product fields (+ jQuery code)
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'display_additional_product_fields', 9 );
function display_additional_product_fields(){
    ?>
    <p class="form-row validate-required" id="image" >
        <label for="file_field"><?php echo __("Upload Image") . ': '; ?>
            <input type='file' name='image' accept='image/*'>
        </label>
    </p>
    <?php
}


// Add custom fields data as the cart item custom data
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_fields_data_as_custom_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );
function add_custom_fields_data_as_custom_cart_item_data( $cart_item, $product_id ){
    if( isset($_FILES['image']) && ! empty($_FILES['image']) ) {
        $upload       = wp_upload_bits( $_FILES['image']['name'], null, file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ) );
        $filetype     = wp_check_filetype( basename( $upload['file'] ), null );
        $upload_dir   = wp_upload_dir();
        $upl_base_url = is_ssl() ? str_replace('http://', 'https://', $upload_dir['baseurl']) : $upload_dir['baseurl'];
        $base_name    = basename( $upload['file'] );

        $cart_item['file_upload'] = array(
            'guid'      => $upl_base_url .'/'. _wp_relative_upload_path( $upload['file'] ), // Url
            'file_type' => $filetype['type'], // File type
            'file_name' => $base_name, // File name
            'title'     => ucfirst( preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $base_name ) ), // Title
        );
        $cart_item['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() ); // Avoid merging items
    }
    return $cart_item;
}

// Display custom cart item data in cart (optional)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_item_data', 10, 2 );
function display_custom_item_data( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( isset( $cart_item['file_upload']['title'] ) ){
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => __( 'Image uploaded', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' =>  str_pad($cart_item['file_upload']['title'], 16, 'X', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '…',
        );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Save Image data as order item meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'custom_field_update_order_item_meta', 20, 4 );
function custom_field_update_order_item_meta( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if ( isset( $values['file_upload'] ) ){
        $item->update_meta_data( '_img_file',  $values['file_upload'] );
    }
}

// Admin orders: Display a linked button + the link of the image file
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta', 'backend_image_link_after_order_itemmeta', 10, 3 );
function backend_image_link_after_order_itemmeta( $item_id, $item, $product ) {
    // Only in backend for order line items (avoiding errors)
    if( is_admin() && $item->is_type('line_item') && $file_data = $item->get_meta( '_img_file' ) ){
        echo '<p><a href="'.$file_data['guid'].'" target="_blank" class="button">'.__("Open Image") . '</a></p>'; // Optional
        echo '<p><code>'.$file_data['guid'].'</code></p>'; // Optional
    }
}

// Admin new order email: Display a linked button + the link of the image file
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'wc_email_new_order_custom_meta_data', 10, 4);
function wc_email_new_order_custom_meta_data( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    // On "new order" email notifications
    if ( 'new_order' === $email->id ) {
        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item ) {
            if ( $file_data = $item->get_meta( '_img_file' ) ) {
                echo '<p>
                    <a href="'.$file_data['guid'].'" target="_blank" class="button">'.__("Download Image") . '</a><br>
                    <pre><code style="font-size:12px; background-color:#eee; padding:5px;">'.$file_data['guid'].'</code></pre>
                </p><br>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Tested in Woocommerce version 4.3.x and working with default WooCommerce products from all types.

Comment: Your code also works on default wordpress template(not in woodmart again) Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Nobody can guess that you are using woodmart templates by magic, so this working answer should be normally the accepted one.

Comment: Totally correct. Thank you for your time assisting me. For reference: woodmart uses ajax for adding to cart and it doesn't support adding images. i will try to tweak the code.

Comment: What if there are multiple images?

Comment: But this code does not show any notification when no file is chosen. The page just redirects to WORDPRESS ERROR page

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a plugin such as Product Addons

https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/

Here’s a link to the documentation that explains specifically about allowing file uploads (they can be free or charge per upload)

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-add-ons/#section-9

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately a plugin doesn't help me because it's a highly customized work. There are many custom fields displayed dynamically based on various scenarios. Everything works, except the file attachment.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a conflict with my template(woodmart)
the code works perfectly on twentytwenty and storefront

i should have thought of this earlier and not bang my head in the wall for a week.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple images if someone needs it.

```
function add_custom_fields_data_as_custom_cart_item_data($cart_item)
{
    $images = ['front-image', 'back-image', 'sleeve-image'];

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        if (isset($_FILES[$image]) && $_FILES[$image]['error'] === 0) {

            $upload       = wp_upload_bits($_FILES[$image]['name'], null, file_get_contents($_FILES[$image]['tmp_name']));
            $filetype     = wp_check_filetype(basename($upload['file']), null);
            $upload_dir   = wp_upload_dir();
            $upl_base_url = is_ssl() ? str_replace('http://', 'https://', $upload_dir['baseurl']) : $upload_dir['baseurl'];
            $base_name    = basename($upload['file']);

            $cart_item['file_upload'][] = array(
                'guid'      => $upl_base_url . '/' . _wp_relative_upload_path($upload['file']), // Url
                'file_type' => $filetype['type'], // File type
                'file_name' => uniqid('logo_upload') . $base_name, // File name
                'title'     => ucfirst(preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $base_name)), // Title
                'position' => $image
            );
            $cart_item['unique_key'] = md5(microtime() . rand()); // Avoid merging items
        }
    }
    return $cart_item;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_fields_data_as_custom_cart_item_data', 10, 3);


// Display custom cart item data in cart 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_item_data', 10, 2);
function display_custom_item_data($cart_item_data, $cart_item)
{

    foreach ($cart_item['file_upload'] as $image) {
        if (isset($image['title'])) {
            $cart_item_data[] = array(
                'name' => __('Image uploaded', 'woocommerce'),
                'value' =>  $image['title']
            );
        }
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Save Image data as order item meta data
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'custom_field_update_order_item_meta', 20, 4);
function custom_field_update_order_item_meta($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order)
{
    if (isset($values['file_upload'])) {
        $item->update_meta_data('_img_files',  $values['file_upload']);
    }
}

// Admin orders: Display a linked button + the link of the image file
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta', 'backend_image_link_after_order_itemmeta', 10, 3);
function backend_image_link_after_order_itemmeta($item_id, $item, $product)
{
    // Only in backend for order line items (avoiding errors)
    if (is_admin() && $item->is_type('line_item') && $files_data = $item->get_meta('_img_files')) {

        $imagesHtml = '';

        foreach ($files_data as $key => $image) {
            $imagesHtml .= '<p><a href="' . $image['guid'] . '" target="_blank" class="button">' . __($image['position']) . '</a></p>'; // Optional
        }

        echo $imagesHtml;
        
    }
}
```