# Add any file upload field to Woo Commerce single products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I has follow this answer as well:
[Add image file upload field to WooCommerce single products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62847710/add-image-file-upload-field-to-woocommerce-single-products)
but it only shows that how can we upload image file. All I need is to upload psd,cdr,eps file as well. Anyone can guide that how to do it. Thanks

Comment: WordPress media library doesn't allow psd,cdr,eps files … So that is about WordPress but not WooCommerce… So you should better ask in [Wordpress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) "how to extend Media Library file types to handle psd,cdr,eps uploads"?.

Comment: I had tried that as well. Now I am adding custom code in wordpress backend and it didn't allowing me to upload psd,cdr or ,eps file

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I had been following your answer that you had given on another question. Your code is only allowing me to upload image file. Now I want to upload psd, cdr files as well. How to allow the these in wordpress backend.